# Material autocomplete not displaying list on click

Tags: angular, list, autocomplete, angular-material, angular6

I have a material autocomplete.

I am making an ngrx call to pull the data.

```
 //parentcomponent.ts
 this.store.select(fromStore.getSearchFormStateMessageTypeListData).subscribe(msgTypeList => {
  if (msgTypeList.length > 0) {
    console.log('msgtypelist ='+msgTypeList)
    for (var i = 0; i < msgTypeList.length; i++) {
      this.messageTypeList.push(msgTypeList[i]);
    }
  }
  else {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.GetGlobalSearchMessageTypeList({}));
  }
})


//parentcomponent.html

 <mat-card style="margin: 1px;">
    <search-form [messageTypeList]="messageTypeList"  (onSearchData)="searchButtonClick($event)" [rowData]="rowData | async">
   </search-form>
</mat-card>
```

From the parent I am passing the msgTypeList to the child.

In the child, I am binding the autocomplete to the list but the list is not displaying anything when we click inside.

It only displays options when we type something in the input box ( which filters the options )

```
 //childcomponent.html
 <form [formGroup]="searchForm" id="searchForm" style="width:100%;height:70%" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<tr>
<td class="input-form" style="padding-right:4%;width:10%">
   <mat-form-field>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Message Type" aria-label="Assignee"  formControlName="msgType" matInput [matAutocomplete]="autoMsgType">
     <mat-autocomplete #autoMsgType="matAutocomplete" placeholder="Message Type" [displayWith]="displayMessageTypeFn">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let messageType of filteredMessageTypeList | async | sort:'msgType'" [value]="messageType">{{messageType.msgType}}</mat-option>
       </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
 </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Below is the child.ts file

```
   //childcomponent.ts
searchForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      direction: [null],
      msgType: [null, Validators.nullValidator],
     });
    this.filterMessageTypeLists();
     }



filterMessageTypeLists() {
    this.filteredMessageTypeList = this.searchForm.controls['msgType'].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith<string | any>(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.msgType),
      map(msgType => msgType ? this._msg_filter(msgType, this.messageTypeList) : this.messageTypeList.slice())
    );
  }


     private _msg_filter(msgType: string, lists: any[]): any[] {
    const filterValue = msgType.toLowerCase();
    return lists.filter(option => option.msgType.toLowerCase().includes(msgType.toLowerCase()))
      }

  displayMessageTypeFn(field?: any): string | undefined {
return field ? field.msgType : undefined;;
 }
```

Issue is if I click in the autocomplete input, it should open the list but nothing displays

[image: No list is shown]

However if we enter anything in the input box, the options are then displayed
[image: List is shown]

Comment: I had to set empty string to formControl first, to display autocomplete dropdown before typing anything in it: `this.searchForm.controls['msgType'].setValue('');`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.

Make sure this.messageTypeList has values in it during the map() call

My issue was that didn't have anything in my array so it showed as blank.

```
ngOnInit() {
// I subscribed to messageTypeList; 
// Then I did my control.onValueChanged( map... map...);
}
```

It should be

```
ngOnInit() {
  ObservableList.subscribe(array => {
     messageTypeList = array;
     control.onValueChanged( // do your mapping filter stuff);
  });
}
```

As long as you have values in your list it should show up.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to call the form.valueChanges just after get your data instead of execute it in init function like this :

```
this.data1.getArticleS().subscribe(a => {
        this.tabArticle = a;
        console.log(a);
        this.filteredArticles = this.stockForm.get('article').valueChanges //erreur angular qui fonctionne bug interpreter ?
            .pipe(
                startWith(''),
                map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
                map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.tabArticle.slice()));

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply set the value for searchForm in ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.searchForm .setValue('');
}

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event on input in your html and call a function on the click event. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Message Type" aria-label="Assignee"  formControlName="msgType" 
    matInput [matAutocomplete]="autoMsgType" (click)="myFunc()" >
```

and in your ts file, declare a boolean variable and set it to false initially. Let's say the variable is `bool`.

Now write the function `myFunc()` and simply toggle that variable like:

```
this.bool = !this.bool;
```

Now in your matautocomplete tag , just set the panelOpen property to the bool variable like this:

```
<mat-autocomplete #autoMsgType="matAutocomplete" placeholder="Message Type" [displayWith]="displayMessageTypeFn" 
     panelOpen="bool">
```

You can set the `bool` variable back to false on some later function in order for it to work properly.

Comment: I found the issue, but need to find a solution. The value changes property in the filterMessageTypeLists function is triggered only on entering some value in the input box. I need to let it to allow the list to load on page load

Comment: you can use setvalue instead of valueChanges.

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredRecipients | async" ...
```

with

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredRecipients = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this.chatService.filterForAutoComplete(value))
      );
 }
```

The problem was that my view (and consequently `this.filteredRecipients`) was being rendered before the `this.chatService` actually recieved the list of recipients that the map function is trying to grab.  So instead I used the following that makes sure the recipients is populated before the map function runs.

In my service:

```
private vAllRecipientsPopulatedSubject = new Subject<any>();
public allRecipientsPopulated$ = this.vAllRecipientsPopulatedSubject.asObservable();
public setRecipients(rcpts: RecipientModel[]) {
    const callback = () => {
      this.vAllRecipientsPopulatedSubject.next();
    };
    this.vAllRecipients = [];
    let itemsProcessed = 0;
    rcpts.forEach(element => {
      this.vAllRecipients.push(element);
      itemsProcessed++;
      if (itemsProcessed === rcpts.length) {
        callback();
      }
    });
}
```

In my controller

```
this.filteredRecipients = combineLatest([this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')), this.chatService.allRecipientsPopulated$])
  .pipe(
    map(([changes, notused]) => this.chatService.filterForAutoComplete(changes))
  );
```