# How to make <mat-autocomplete> show when click on input

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use a material autocomplete form linked to a input with Angular 8

I'm new to Angular and I'm still learning.
I've already tried some solution I found on stackoverflow without success ( e.g: [Material autocomplete not displaying list on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319615/material-autocomplete-not-displaying-list-on-click))

Here's my HTML page:

```html
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        placeholder="Equipment"
        aria-label="Number"
        [formControl]="machineControl"
        [formControl]="machineFilter"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
        #machineinput
      />
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

And here's my Typescript page:

```js
export class DocumentsListComponent implements OnInit {
  machineControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  @ViewChild('machineControl', { static: true }) input: ElementRef;

 constructor(public restApi: DocumentsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {


    this.restApi.getList().then(res => {
      [...]
      for (const docs of this.Document) {
        if (this.options.some(machine => machine === docs.machine)) {
        } else {
          this.options.push(docs.machine);
        }
      }
    });

    this.filteredOptions = this.machineControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );

    private _filter(value: string): string[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

        return this.options.filter(option => 
        option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    }
```

I expect the auto-complete form to show up on input click but I need to type at least 1 character for it to show (Removing this character still show the auto-complete form)

Comment: None of the examples here work for you: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal I don't see what I'm missing from the "Filter autocomplete" example on this page.

Comment: does this work if you have hardcoded values instead of calling from your rest api ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal Indeed it works ! If you know why it reacts like that, at least I have a new lead to dig.

Edit: it seems it does not load my list of options before I type 1 character. If I put hardcoded values it works and when I type 1 character it shows my values from the API.

Comment: you should be able to get help... basically, the dropdown list `this.filteredOptions` needs to be assigned after the rest api service calls returns a result

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for it right now, will answer my own question if I find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed, thanks to @AkberIqbal

My issue was my autocomplete was filled with an empty list before my API call returns a result.

To fix this, I assign my filteredOptions in the restApi call (At the beginning because putting it at the end didn't work):

```js
    this.restApi.getList().then(res => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);

      this.filteredOptions = this.machineControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );

      [...]

      for (const docs of this.Document) {
        if (this.options.some(machine => machine === docs.machine)) {
        } else {
          this.options.push(docs.machine);
        }
      }
    });
```

Again, thank you @AkberIqbal, I was working on this for too long and you helped me in no time.

Answer (score 2):

As I had the same issue and this solution was not listed, I will post mine.
For me was enough to patch the value of the input with an empty string after the data was received from the API.

in your case add

```
this.restApi.getList().then(res => {
  [...]
  this.machineControl.pachValue('') // add this line
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is to remove async function in HTML and changing the type of filteredOptions from Observable to an Array:

```js
  form: FormGroup;
  code = new FormControl();
  options: Permission[];
  filteredOptions: Permission[];

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SelectModalComponent>,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private api: DynamicService,
  ) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      code: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.api.getAll('/api/permission', null).subscribe((permissions: Permission[]) => {
      this.options = permissions;
      this.filteredOptions = permissions;
      console.log(this.options);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.code.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      ).subscribe(ret => {
        this.filteredOptions = ret;
      });
  }

  private _filter(value: any): Permission[] {
    if (this.options && typeof (value) === 'string') {
      return this.options.filter(option => option.code.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
    }
  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

  <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayout="column">

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Permissões" matInput [formControl]="code" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>

      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option.code">
          {{option.code}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>

    </mat-form-field>

    <button color="primary" mat-raised-button fxAlign>Salvar</button>
  </div>


</form>
```